# Разница между реализациями React.setState()

Tags: reactjs

Будьте добры, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем разница между двумя реализациями с использованием setState():

1)

```
onTextChange(event) {
    let form = this.state.form;

    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;

    form[fieldName] = fieldValue;
    this.setState({form: form});
  }
```

2)

```
onTextChange(event) {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;

    this.setState({form: 
      {[fieldName]: fieldValue}
    });
  }
```

Хочу обратить внимание, что this.state они обновляют по-разному. Поскажите пожалуйста, почему?

Comment: а что именно непонятно? во 2-м случае, вы полностью перетираете состояние form, в 1-м случае вы изменяете только fieldName..., но тут дело не в поведение setState а в том ка вы управляете объектом form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае вы напрямую мутируете объект **state**, что вообще-то не поощряется.

Второй путь более "каноничный" и правильный. Нашёл [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060641/react-changing-the-state-without-using-setstate-must-avoid-it) на SO, если вкратце, то: мутируйте напрямую только если понимаете что вы делаете и зачем, иначе лучше меняйте содержимое объектов внутри стейта копируя объекты (или создавая новые, как у вас во 2-м случае)

Comment: Прошу уважаемое сообщество поправить меня, если я ошибаюсь